# Python: Why won't my Database show in this window?

Tags: python, sql, user-interface, pyqt

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
import sys
class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create()
    def create(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('SQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('management.db')
        self.db.open()

        self.x()
        self.layout =QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table_view)
        self.widget=QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def x(self):
        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.setTable("management")
        self.table_view=QTableView()
        self.table_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.table_view.model().select()
        self.table_view.show()
ap = QApplication(sys.argv)
wi = Test()
wi.show()
wi.raise_()
ap.exec_()
```

The code above is a simple object that i intend to create a window to view the contents of my database. But all it produces is a blank white box. Thanks!

the database has data in it and consists of different tables (enitities). That's all i can say.

Comment: ... and what's wrong with the white box? The white box means that the `QTableView` *is* indeed shown. About the fact that it is empty maybe is because you don't have data in your database? We cannot reproduce if you don't provide more information about the database.

Comment: this is my first question on here, sorry! (updated)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using an invlaid driver type.

The Qt docs for [QSqlDatabase](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#QSqlDatabase-2) say you want one of these:

```
The currently available driver types are:  

Driver Type  Description  
QDB2         IBM DB2  
QIBASE       Borland InterBase Driver  
QMYSQL       MySQL Driver  
QOCI         Oracle Call Interface Driver  
QODBC        ODBC Driver (includes Microsoft SQL Server)  
QPSQL        PostgreSQL Driver  
QSQLITE      SQLite version 3 or above  
QSQLITE2     SQLite version 2  
QTDS         Sybase Adaptive Server
```

So it looks like you need to try:

```
    self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
```